# About $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V,W$ are two vector space and let $S\subseteq V$. Define: $$S^{0}=\{T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)\mid~T(x)=0, \forall x\in S\}$$ The problem aks me to verify $S^{0}$ is a subspace of $V$ and if $V_1,V_2$ are two subspaces, then $$(V_1+V_2)^{0}=V^0_1\cap V^0_2$$ Please help me to overcome the second part. I did the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by a double inclusion, suppose that $W\in(V_1+V_2)^0$, then for every $x\in V_1$ we have that $W(x)=0$ and similarly for $x\in V_2$, therefore $W\in V_1^0$ and $W\in V_2^0$, so $W$ is in the intersection.

The opposite direction is similar, and I leave it to you. Note that you will have to use the definition of $V_1+V_2$ and the linearity of $W$ here.

Comment: Is it true that if $V_1\subseteq V_2$ then $V^0_2\subseteq V^0_1$?

Comment: Basil, it is. Note the definitions: if $W\in V_2^0$ then every $x\in V_1$ is in $V_2$ and so $W(x)$ equals to...?

Comment: Thank you Asaf. I undrestood.